# How to have Powershell process files in a folder and pass a CMD command with variables

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am writing a Powershell script that will take all the files in a user specified folder and pass them one by one to the command line, which will then dump the resulting files (.CSVs) into another user specified folder.  I'm trying to use the same filename for the CSV as the original file.  The command has to be executed from a specific folder ( C:\Program Files (x86)\Reporter).

This is what I have so far, but I can't seem to make anything work past `write-host` - for loops, iterations, strings, you name it, Powershell and I are no bueno.

```
pushd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reporter\"

$filename = read-host "Enter the complete path of Original files"
$csvfiles = read-host "Enter the complete path for the CSVs"
write-host $filename
write-host $csvfiles
$reporter = "reporter.exe /rptcsv", $filename + ".csv", $filename

[$filename.string]::join(" ",(gci))
```

The command line command has to be `program.exe /rptcsv <file being created> <file being used>` .  I need it to process them one at a time, waiting for the previous one to finish before processing the second one.  The amount of original files will vary, so I just need it to process them they've all been gone through.  I've done batch files and some Python, but have never used Powershell.  I had previously done this in Python, only to be told that now we need Powershell instead- this is my first venture into Powershell and it's a doozy.  Can this be done?

Edit: Answer!!

This is the working code:

```
pushd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reporter"

$src = read-host "Enter the complete path of the folder with original files"
$dst = read-host "Enter the complete path of the folder for the CSVs"
write-host $src
write-host $dst
$reporter = 'reporter.exe /rptcsv'

Get-ChildItem $src | % {
  $outfile = Join-Path $dst ($_.Name + ".csv")
  cmd /c $reporter $outfile $_.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `reporter.exe` doesn't run asynchronously (i.e. does not return immediately while processing the file in the background) something like this should work:

```
pushd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reporter"

$src = read-host "Enter the complete path of the folder with original files"
$dst = read-host "Enter the complete path of the folder for the CSVs"
write-host $src
write-host $dst

Get-ChildItem $src | % {
  $outfile = Join-Path $dst ($_.Name + ".csv")
  reporter.exe /rptcsv $outfile $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: I tried that and got these errors:
The term 'reporter.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, scri
pt file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\boo\Desktop\testing.ps1:12 char:12
+     reporter.exe <<<<  /rptcsv $outfile $_.FullName
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (reporter.exe:String) [], CommandN
   otFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Users\boo\Desktop\testing.ps1:11 char:22
+     $outfile = Join-Path <<<<  $dst ($_.Name + ".csv")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingVa
   lidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,M
   icrosoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand

Comment: First error: `reporter.exe` is not in `$env:PATH`. Either `cd` (or `pushd`) into the program directory, or specify the program with its full path. Second error: `$dst` is not initialized.

Comment: Should I cd to the directory with the original files, or the one that I have to be in to run the command (C:\Program Files (x86)\Reporter)? I ask because at the top of the script I had `pushd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reporter\"`.  (Sorry, I accidentally left that line out.)  I've added it to the original post.

Comment: The directory containing `reporter.exe`.

Comment: Ok, I added `pushd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reporter\"` as the first line in the script and am still having the same errors.  Does Powershell realize that $src, $dst, and C:\Program Files (x86)\Reporter\ are all different?  Is it trying to search for $dst in the Reporter folder?

Comment: You're prompting for the complete path, so naturally the code assumes that `$src` and `$dst` are the full paths of the source and destination folders.

Comment: I did finally get the code working, but had to use cmd /c instead of giving it the filename.  I've edited the original post.  Works like a charm, thanks!